# Sequence Covergent $\iff$ absolutely convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it correct that the sequence $a_n \rightarrow 0 $$\iff |a_n|\rightarrow 0$?

I have it written down but I am unaware where I got it from. If so is it true for any limit?

Comment: (Notice that it isn't true if the limit is nonzero.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a_n \to 0$. Then, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $|a_n - 0| < \varepsilon$.

Thus, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $||a_n| - 0| < \varepsilon$, as $||a_n| - 0| = |a_n - 0| = |a_n|$, and so $|a_n| \to 0$ as well.

The other direction is similar.